# CORBA Naming Service returns incorrect location of a registered object

Tags: java, corba

I have a simple setup with several objects registered at orbd. Remote client initializes connection to the ORB and tries to resolve a reference to the Naming Serice (IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContextExt:1.0). So far it's all fine - ORB returns giop.iiop.host/giop.iiop.port pair. When reference to the Naming Service is resolved, client tries to *resolve_str()* one of the registered objects. This time, Naming Service returns completely different pair giop.iiop.host/giop.iiop.port for the object (not the host/port of a Naming Service) - I don't know anything about them. When client tries to call a method on a resolved object, it fails, as the host/port pair is not configured in the firewall. Could you please explain, why it's happening?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced the same problem, when I moved once ORB from one host to another. Context was cached, and Naming Service was responding with the location/port of the previous host. If it's so, try removing /orb.db - it should help.